# Linux GUI Database Manager

Tags: linux, database, gui

Does anyone Know any KDE application for working with databases in a unified way? It must support several DBs (sqlite, MySQL, Oracle). GTK apps are also welcome :)

Comment: Here's a nice [comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found this....

[Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/)

- [Features](http://www.aquafold.com/d75/docs/index.html)
- [Screenshots](http://www.aquafold.com/screenshots.html)
- [Download](http://www.aquafold.com/downloads.html)

> Aqua Data Studio is a complete Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for database developers. It provides four major areas of functionality: 1) Database query and administration tools; 2) a suite of compare tools for databases, source control and file systems; 3) a complete and integrated source control client for Subversion (SVN) and CVS; and 4) a database modeler as powerful as the best standalone database diagramming tools.

OS Support:

- ADS for Windows
- ADS for Linux
- ADS for OS X
- ADS for Solaris
- ADS for Java Platform

RDBMS Support:

- Oracle - 11g/10g/9i/8i
- DB2 iSeries
- DB2 LUW - 9/8/7
- MS SQL Server - 2008/2005/2000/7/MSDE
- Sybase ASE - 15/12.x/11.x
- Sybase Anywhere - 10/9/8
- Sybase IQ - 12.x
- Informix IDS - 11/10/9.x/7.x
- PostgreSQL - 8.x/7.x
- MySQL - 5/4.x/3.x
- Apache Derby 10.x
- Generic JDBC Platform
- Generic ODBC

Comment: A very nice one! :)

Comment: When you say "Found this..." it really means that you never ever used it?

Comment: FYI This isn't free. OP didn't specify, but though it should be mentioned.

Comment: I believe this one has most features one may need, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

[**SQuirreL SQL**](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) is a Java-based application that can connect to several DBMS, providing there is a JDBC driver for it.

It's free and open-source.

Answer (score 0):

Kexi may be interesting too... Of course it won't be and won't look that advanced like Aqua Data Studio does... Kexi's more like (from a Windows view) what MS Access is to databases while Aqua Data Studio more looks like SQL Management Studio looking at the screenshots.

But Aqua looks very interesting - I'll keep an eye on that. +1

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL: [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
For Oracle SQL: [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)